# Dynamically generated table element - scrollbar id?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnAdd", function () {

            var functionName = document.getElementById("selectFunction");
            var Text = functionName.options[functionName.selectedIndex].text
            var Value = functionName.options[functionName.selectedIndex].value;

            $("#tblWorkpack tbody").append(
                 "<tr>" +
                 "<td><input type='text' disabled class='form-control' value='" + Text + "' /></td>" +
                 "<td><select id='xyz'></select></td>" +
                "</tr>");

            // Find the id of dynamically generated for the new Dropdownbox 
            var responsibleUsersDropdown = $('#tblWorkpack tr td:nth-child(2)').attr('id');
            alert(responsibleUsersDropdown)
            var Url = '@Url.Action("FindUser","Home")';
            $.post(Url, { Functionid: Value }, function (data) {
                responsibleUsersDropdown.empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    responsibleUsersDropdown.append('<option value?+data[i].UserId+?="">' + data[i].FullName + '</Option>');
                }
            });

            selectedFunctions.push(Value);
        });
```

So I am trying to create a dynamic row on the click of a button. The `'btnAdd'` on click event creates a new row that has a textbox and a dropdownbox. I need to make an ajax call based on the value in the textbox get the items from the back-end based on it and fill it into the dropdown. I need to get the id of dynamically created Dropdown which I am unable to retrieve. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right of your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the id is not magically created when you add an element via jQuery.  the id is an html attribute that you would set yourself.

What you're really looking for is some sort of way to refer to the element that you created, which really has nothing to do with html id.  You can accomplish that by doing the following (see my starred comments below for an explanation):

```
    $(document).on("click", "#btnAdd", function () {

        var functionName = document.getElementById("selectFunction");
        var Text = functionName.options[functionName.selectedIndex].text
        var Value = functionName.options[functionName.selectedIndex].value;

        $("#tblWorkpack tbody").append(
             "<tr>" +
             "<td><input type='text' disabled class='form-control' value='" + Text + "' /></td>" +
             "<td><select id='xyz'><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option></select></td>" +
            "</tr>");

        // ***** set the variable $responsibleUsersDropdown to point to the last tr
        // created.  Note that the $ in front of the variable name is simply a  
        // convention to indicate that this variable is a jQuery object.
        var $responsibleUsersDropdown = $("#tblWorkpack tbody tr:last-of-type");


        var Url = '@Url.Action("FindUser","Home")';
        $.post(Url, { Functionid: Value }, function (data) {
            // ***** $responsibleUsersDropdown in the callback will refer to the value set 
            // in the enclosing function above.
            $responsibleUsersDropdown.empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $responsibleUsersDropdown.append('<option value?+data[i].UserId+?="">' + data[i].FullName + '</Option>');
            }
        });

        selectedFunctions.push(Value);
    });
```

**UPDATE:**
See this working fiddle.  I've simulated the data returned by the AJAX call since we can't run that form the fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/kqa8jff7/  You had numerous bugs in the code with I've fixed below.  You can take this code, put it into your site, and reenable the AJAX call and it should work.

```
var selectedFunctions = [];

$(document).on("click", "#btnAdd", function () {

    var functionName = document.getElementById("selectFunction");
    var Text = functionName.options[functionName.selectedIndex].text
    var Value = functionName.options[functionName.selectedIndex].value;

    // change this code around.  first we create a new javascript object with just the new row
    var $new_row = $("<tr>" +
        "<td><input type='text' disabled class='form-control' value='" + Text + "' /></td>" +
        "<td><select></select></td>" +
        "</tr>");
    // now append that as before:
    $("#tblWorkpack tbody").append($new_row);

    // the following line was wrong - this(...) doesn't mean anything
    // var $responsibleUsersDropdown = this("#tblWorkpack tbody tr td:nth-child(2)");
    // anyhow change that line so that we look at the $new_row and find the select within it
    var $responsibleUsersDropdown = $new_row.find('select');

    // comment out some of the code below and simulate the ajax call:
    /*
    var Url = '@Url.Action("FindUser","Home")';
    $.post(Url, {
        Functionid: Value
    }, function (data) { */
    // simulate data result from ajax
    var data = [{
        UserID: '1',
        FullName: 'john doe'
    }, {
        UserID: '2',
        FullName: 'jane doe'
    }];

    $responsibleUsersDropdown.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // you had the wrong variable name below (forgot the $)
        $responsibleUsersDropdown.append('<option value?+data[i].UserId+?="">' + data[i].FullName + '</Option>');
    }
    /*
    });
*/
    var i = 0;
    i = i + 1;

    selectedFunctions.push(Value);

});

$(document).on("click", "#btnDelete", function () {
    $("#tblWorkpack tr:last").remove();
    selectedFunctions.pop();
});

function SetWorkpacks() {
    var tempvalue = document.getElementById('selectedwp');
    tempvalue.value = selectedFunctions;

}
```

Comment: Hello Manishie, Thank you so much for taking the time to look into my question. Unfortunately the solution didn't work me . I dont know whats the issue...

Comment: well i'm unable to test this myself as i don't have access to your code or server.  so there might be some errors some where.  this is meant to give you the general sense for what you need to do.  are you getting an error message?  please provide more details as to what's happening...

Comment: I am not getting any error message. The thing is you understood my problem quite accurately. I need to get the Id of the newly created dropdown everytime user click on the add button. But some how it just clears up the content of 2nd cell and it appears blank. or it make a epty scroll bar appear

Comment: Please go to jsfiddle.com and create something to simulate the situation, then I'll go in and fix it.

Comment: k i'll look at it now.